# Small Procedure with Cursor for autocreate rows in tables (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql

i created an event that execute one time per month. Three tables are important here, Cuota(fee), Alumno(studient) and CuotaxAlumno(fee per studient).

My objective is create a row in table Cuota(fee) one time per month and then with that fee create a payment row for every studient (in table CuotaxAlumno).

I having syntax error in te FETCH line, line 19, and i don't find the problem. i will appreciate the help.

IS WORKING NOW. CODE UPDATED 13-04-2017 Thanks!

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE crearCuotas()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE referenciaMonto INT;
    DECLARE referenciaAlumno INT;
    DECLARE referenciaCuota INT;
    DECLARE fecha DATE;
    DECLARE cursorAlumno CURSOR FOR SELECT idAlumno FROM alumno WHERE idEstado=1;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    SET referenciaMonto = (SELECT idMontoCuota FROM montocuota ORDER BY idMontoCuota DESC LIMIT 1);
    SET fecha = CURDATE();
    INSERT INTO cuota (idMontoCuota, fecha) VALUES(referenciaMonto, fecha);
    SET referenciaCuota = (SELECT idCuota FROM cuota ORDER BY idCuota DESC LIMIT 1);

    OPEN cursorAlumno;

    fetch_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cursorAlumno INTO referenciaAlumno;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE fetch_loop;
        END IF;
        INSERT INTO cuotaxalumno(idAlumno, idCuota, idEstado) VALUES(referenciaAlumno, referenciaCuota, 5);
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cursorAlumno;
END;

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What error is thrown?. You haven't defined done variable. You haven't defined Handler ([14.6.7.2 DECLARE ... HANDLER Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare-handler.html)) and as mentioned in the answer, include a loop label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a loop label:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE crearCuotas()
BEGIN
  /* yada */
  OPEN cursorAlumno;

  fetch_loop: LOOP
      FETCH cursorAlumno INTO referenciaAlumno;
      IF done THEN
          LEAVE fetch_loop;
      END IF;
      INSERT INTO cuotaxalumno (idAlumno, idCuota, idEstado) 
             VALUES (referenciaAlumno, referenciaCuota, 5);
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cursorAlumno;
END;
```

This is because while the label is not required for creating a loop, [it is required for the leave statement.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/leave.html)

Comment: thank you! but the ":" after the fetch_loop give me an error. MYSQL say "unexpected caracter close to :"

Comment: Now is working, i updated the code at the top. but your label was the key of everything. Thank you!!!